Unresolved reference while publishing library to maven local
I am publishing a android library to maven local but some code (specially DSL and extension functions cannot be resolved)
Please find below my configurations :
library/buid.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    id("precompiled_plugin.android-library-base")
    kotlin("android")
    id("maven-publish")
}
android {
    namespace = ".."
    publishing {
        singleVariant("debug") {
            withSourcesJar()
        }
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xexplicit-api=strict"
    }
}

dependencies {
}

publishing {
    publications {
        register<MavenPublication>("sdkLibrary") {
            groupId = "<group_id>"
            artifactId = "<artifact_id>"
            version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

            afterEvaluate {
                from(components["debug"])
            }
        }
    }
}

precompiled_plugin/android-library-base.kts :
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

android {
    compileSdk = COMPILE_SDK
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = MIN_SDK
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            consumerProguardFiles(
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JAVA_VERSION // = JAVA 11
        targetCompatibility = JAVA_VERSION // = JAVA 11
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
    }
    packaging {
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JVM_TARGET // = JAVA 11
    }
    tasks.withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}

ksp {
    arg("KOIN_CONFIG_CHECK","true")
}

dependencies {
}

precompiled_plugin/android-library-base.kts :
Can someone help me with this please?
Thanks in advance

Finally fixed my issue. The problem was due to exclude META-INF/*. So the solution is to remove the line in my precompiled-plugin:
precompiled_plugin/android-library-base.kts :
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

android {
    ...

    //to remove to fix the issue
    /** packaging {
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
    } **/
}

...

